# NoMethodError в ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Вот такая ошибка выходит при запуске на localhost

```
NoMethodError in Products#index

Showing d:/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <h1>Listing products</h1>
2: 
3: <table>
4:   <%@product.each do|product| %>
5:       <tr class="<%=cycle('list_line_odd ','list_line_ even') %>">
6:         <td>
7:           <%=image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_ image') %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите @products в контролере ProductsController. Выведь в неё передаёте массив с продуктами?  Во вьюшке её и вызывайте.

```
 <% @products.each do |product| %>
```

Comment: Массивом это назвать можно довольно условно, в идеальном случае это `AR::Relation`, и не нужно писать `.all`, лучше использовать pagination.

Comment: Ну я, эцсамое, не хотел путать человека. Если уж на то пошло, то и без pluck-а ему не обойтись (:

Comment: Я ее и вызывал во вьюшке

Answer (score 3):

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Это означает, что @product у вас содержит nil, который, соответственно, не имеет метода each.
Вам надо, скорее всего, вызывать @products. И не забудьте проверить на nil перед циклом, на всякий...

Comment: Проверять на `nil` незачем, запрос к коллекции в AR не вернёт `nil`.

Comment: В целом -- да. Но проверять на пустость, чтобы правильно оформить вывод отсутствия результата и избежать ошибок -- хорошая практика для новичка.